# Testing for no array intersection in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$result = array_intersect($contacts1, $contacts2);
```

This generates:

```
Array
(
[21] => 
[22] => 
[23] => 
[24] => 
[25] => 
[26] => 
[28] =>
```

I have the following if statement:

```
if (empty($result)) { // i.e. NO INTERECTION
```

I just realized that this will not work as a test for no intersection because many elements are produced, all with the value null. Given this what is the best way to test for intersection of 2 arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if all the values are null (if you know that no null's can exist in your arrays).
You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function.

For example:

```
$result = array_filter(array_intersect($contacts1, $contacts2));
```

That way, all nulls will be removed, and the result (if no intersecion exists) will be an empty array.

UPDATE:
As said in the comment, this will remove also non-null values.
A revised version is to use the callback function:

```
function filterOnlyNulls($elem) {
    return $elem !== null;
}

$result = array_filter(array_intersect($contacts1, $contacts2), "filterOnlyNulls");
```

Answer (score 3):

If NULLs are in the array, then `array_intersect` will return them as being in both arrays.

```
$contacts1 = array("bob", "jane", NULL, NULL);
$contacts2 = array("jim", "john", NULL, NULL);
$result = array_intersect($contacts1, $contacts2);
print_r( $result );
```

> Array
>   (
>       [2] => 
>       [3] => 
>   )

You can filter each array before the intersection using `array_filter`. It takes a callback function, but by default all entries equal to FALSE will be removed, including NULLs.

```
$result2 = array_intersect(array_filter($contacts1), array_filter($contacts2));
print_r( $result2 );
```

> Array
>   (
>   )

Use the [callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) if you want to specifically filter only NULLs, or what your requirements are.

```
function mytest($val) {
   return $val !== NULL;   
}
$result3 = array_intersect(array_filter($contacts1, "mytest"), array_filter($contacts2, "mytest"));
print_r( $result3 );
```

> Array
>   (
>   )